# Making a database application with just JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, web, client-server

I need to make a dead simple web application. Users hit a static HTML page and enter some basic info (name, and comment). When they hit submit, I want to store this info in either a CSV file or a sqlite on the hosting server. I know all of this is possible with django/python or ror/ruby but is there anyway to do this with just JavaScript?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I suppose if you used node on the server then yes. If what you mean though it that you just want to tell the server to save the data then something still has to be on the server (node app, php, etc) to accept that request and do something about it. You could always look in to something like [FireBase](https://www.firebase.com/) - Not exactly what you are asking for, but then you wouldn't have to manage the data on your own server.

Comment: There are plenty of hosts out there that provide mySQL.  I don't know why you would choose to avoid ustilizing it.  If you're looking for dead simple, you are actually going the other way, and making it more complicated, if you intend to avoid existing tools.

Answer (score 0):

There's few ways to handle this, using just javascript. Which is to use a hosted Backend-as-a-Service.

You would need to make API calls on the client end, and will be able to connect to it without having to rely on a backend technology.

Most of these technologies are built for mobile, but you can still use it to build it on your static HTML pages. (cross browser issues may vary).

Here are some:

- Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web-quickstart.html)
- Parse (https://parse.com/docs/js_guide)

There's more out there if you google Backend as a service.

If you are looking for something more simple, just need to take information and store it (like a form), then I would suggest looking at these services:

- Wufoo (http://www.wufoo.com/)
- jotform (http://www.jotform.com/)

Hope it helps!